# Does the notation $\int f(x,y)\partial x$ make sense $\left(\text{where } f(x,y)=\dfrac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, notation, partial-derivative

I am currently studying PDE's where the integration of partial derivative is commonplace. I have seen that in a lot of literature the integral of a partial derivative is just written as

$$\int f(x,y)dx$$

But I find that if you were to write something like $\int f(x,y)\partial x$ it would be much clearer that the integral will have an arbitrary function rather than just a constant. In my head this makes sense but I was wondering if there reason this convention is not widely adopted or if it is even correct to write an integral like this at all?

Comment: @LL3.14 I think that your comment would be fine if posted as an answer.

Comment: What notation is widely adopted in contrast to the one you might prefer has to do with taste, democracy, tradition but little to do with mathematics itself. Personally I follow the crowd and most importantly I spend a few words to explain if necessary what my notation means.

Comment: There is more than taste, democracy and tradition. One should still try for example to be at least coherent ... here are other advantages one can think about when choosing a notation https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366070/what-are-the-benefits-of-writing-vector-inner-products-as-langle-u-v-rangle

Answer (score 1):

You are not integrating a derivative or a partial derivative of $f$, but just the function $f$ itself with respect to one variable. You can see $\mathrm dx$ (the Lebesgue measure) as the derivative of the function $x$, but then it only depends on one variable, so there is no reason to write a $∂$ symbol. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3801916/working-with-infinitesimals-of-the-form-dfx-for-example-dax-and-relating/3807217#3807217) for more about the notation $\mathrm dx$.

The notation $\mathrm d f$ on the contrary was already chosen to be the (total) differential of $f$, which is why one then has to denote with a $\partial f$ the partial derivatives.