# why does integration by parts work?

Tags: integration

$$\int u(x)v'(x)\;\text dx = u(x)v(x) - \int u'(x)v(x)\;\text dx$$
or more compactly:
$$\int u\;\text dv = uv - \int v\;\text du$$
I get how we get the formula, my main question is why
$$\int u \;dv$$

is considered the integral of $uv$; it looks like it's the integral of $u$ with respect to $\text d v$ which isn't the same?

Comment: It is in effect the integration of  $\frac{d}{dx}\left( u(x)v(x)\right) = v(x)\frac{d}{dx} u(x) + u(x)\frac{d}{dx} v(x)$ rearranged

Comment: If your problem is about the notation, here $\int u\,\mathrm dv$ means $\int u\,v'$. There are some notation inconsistencies about this $d$ when doing measure integration. You can look at the end of my answer here for more details https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3801916/working-with-infinitesimals-of-the-form-dfx-for-example-dax-and-relating/3807217#3807217

Answer (score 0):

$\int uv’dx=\int udv$

You can see this using abuse of notation:

$\int uv’dx=\int u \frac{dv}{dx}dx=\int udv$

I call this an abuse because in reality, this being true is *why* we use the notation that we use, not the other way around. Still, it should make sense from the chain rule.

Now, the rest of integration by parts is just the product rule for differentiation, but “backwards.” That should be clear just from rearranging some terms around.

For completeness, I will show it here:

$\frac{d}{dx}(uv)=uv’+vu’$

That is simply the product rule. Now subtract $vu’$ from each side and then integrate with respect to $x$, resulting in:

$\int d(uv)-\int vdu=\int udv$

$uv-\int vdu=\int udv$

Which was what we aimed to show.

Comment: ∫uv′dx=∫udv is the integral of u with respect to v? this doesnt answer why that is equal to the integral of uv

Comment: Well it isn’t equal to that. It is equal to $uv-\int vdu$. Which like I said, is the product rule “backwards” with some terms rearranged

Comment: I edited my answer to include the full proof.

Answer (score 0):

First take the power rule. $$\frac{d}{dx}[uv] = u'v + uv'$$ Now $$u'v = \frac{d}{dx}[uv] - uv'$$ Now integrate both sides. $$\int{u'v} = uv - \int{uv'}$$

Answer (score -3):

## Product rule: $$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)g(x)) = f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)$$
Integrate both sides
$$f(x)g(x) = \int f'(x)g(x) \thinspace dx+\int g'(x)f(x) \thinspace dx$$

$$\int f'(x)g(x) \thinspace dx=f(x)g(x)-\int g'(x)f(x) \thinspace dx$$
Let $f(x) = v, \thinspace g(x) = u$
$$\int u \thinspace dv=uv- \int v \thinspace du$$

Comment: A little correction: The first formula is the Product Rule. The Chain Rule is (f(g(x)))'=f'(g(x))g'(x). Otherwise this is the correct proof.

Comment: changes were made